# Why the ageing population creates problems for a country to fund old-age social protection program and what solution do we have?

Tags: nonexpert, welfare-economics, social-welfare, social-security

Senior citizens are considered as one of the vulnerable groups and therefore, they need some social protection during their old age. However, we also face the worldwide trend of an ageing population.

- If a country just starts planning for their old-age protection during this time, how could the program be financed since there will be an issue to fund the program?
- Can re-employment after retirement minimize the vulnerability faced by senior citizens or will it just create other problems?
- Are there any other options that can be used to address the issue of funding old-age protection?

Comment: This looks like school essay question, what sources did you consult, what research did you do before asking for help here?